# I keep getting a slight null error when using stream builder in flutter

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I keep getting a slight null error before displaying my items. Please can I get help on the best way to use streambuilder without encountering any error?

Comment: Can you share a code snippet so that someone at SO can take a look and help you out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ConnectionState`:

```
          StreamBuilder(
            stream:  Firestore.instance.collection('stores').document(currentUserUID).snapshots(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                return ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: 1,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return ListTile(
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          title: Text(snapshot.data.data["about"]),
                          leading: Text(
                            snapshot.data.data["location"],
                          ));
                    });
              } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
                return Text("No data");
              }
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ConnectionState-class.html

Comment: You can not put ConnectionState while working with StreamBuilder, because the Stream is always active. You have to use snapshot.hasData. You may use ConnectionState with FutureBuilder no problem

Answer (score 0):

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
stream:
    Firestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
builder: (context, snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasError)
    return Center(child:Text('${snapshot.error.toString()}'));
  if (snapshot.hasData) {
    final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = snapshot
        .data.documents;
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: documents.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => RestaurantCard(
        documents[index].documentID,
        name: documents[index].data['name'],
        address: documents[index].data['address'],
        image: documents[index].data['photo'],
      ),
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    );
  } else {
    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  }
},
```

)