# Firestore query is returning data but Futurebuilder saying it cannot be null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, future

I am trying to build a list from documents i have in Firestore. below is my Future function:

```
Future getBuyerList() async {

await Firestore.instance.collection('Deals').where('buyer_id',isEqualTo: uid_global).snapshots().listen((data) {
  data.documents.forEach((doc) {

    print('in function -  ${doc["car"]}');


    print(doc.data);


  });
});


}
```

The above runs fine in the debugger. it shows the full list of items i am expecting to put into the List.

My Future Builder in my widget tree is as follows:

```
FutureBuilder(

                future: getBuyerList(),

                builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {


                if(snapshot.hasData){
                  if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){

                    return Center(

                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),

                    );


                  }else{

                    Center(

                      child: Text('data loaded')

                    );

                  }

                }else if (snapshot.hasError){

                  Text('no data');

                }

                },
              ),
```

I have not yet loaded the snapshot into the Listview as i am trying to get the FutureBuilder to atleast run successfully. but i keep getting a FutureBuilder null error.

[image: Null error on Future Builder.]

I tried running the function as a non void function as well by returning a list but then i get an error on compile saying i cannot assign a Map to Future>.

Please help.

@Peter Haddad's answer was correct but i also needed to make a change to the builder by adding `AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>`:

```
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add return when using the `FutureBuilder`:

```
           FutureBuilder(
                future: getBuyerList(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.hasData){
                  if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  }else{
                   Center(
                      child: Text('data loaded')
                    );
                  }
                }else if (snapshot.hasError){
                  Text('no data');
                }
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                },
              ),
```

`return CircularProgressIndicator();` since the `AsyncWidgetBuilder` returns a `Widget`. Also if the `FutureBuilder` is the top widget in the `build` function then you need to return it:

```
return FutureBuilder( /*...*/)
```

Regarding the function `getBuyerList()` do the following:

```
  Future<QuerySnapshot> getBuyerList() async {
    return await Firestore.instance
        .collection('Deals')
        .where('buyer_id', isEqualTo: uid_global)
        .getDocuments();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, But now the circular progress bar seems to be showing all the time. the issue seems to be that the list data is not being passed into Futurebuilder even though it is properly retrieving in the Future. It shows up in the console.

Comment: still stuck on the circular progress. if I try to print the `snapshot.data` inside the future builder i get the following inside the console `I/flutter (25272): inside future - Instance of 'QuerySnapshot'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61698823/i-keep-getting-a-slight-null-error-when-using-stream-builder-in-flutter/61699495#61699495 check this to know how to use futurebuilder

Comment: u need to print(snapshot.data.data["car"]);

Comment: flutter doesn't allow me to put in the second `.data`. i have even tried using streambuilder for this. nothing seems to work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213576/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-waseem-ahmed).